# Difference between browser-perf and protractor-perf and perfjankie

Tags: node.js, npm, performance-testing, protractor

I am looking into tools performance testing with Protractor. I came across browser-perf and protractor-perf.

protractor-perf is Based on browser-perf.

As far as I understand, browser-perf is preferrable in case one wants to have a CI for performance testing. This is not however available if we use protractor-perf.

Perfjankie is seemingly used for running browser-perf tests. But then there's seemingly browserPerf.runner available for running browser-perf tests too.

I am not able to understand all these available options and their specific differences for Performance testing using Protractor.

Please provide your valuable suggestions/inputs/explanations to help understand the same.
Which to use and When to use!

Regards,
Sakshi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained by Prashuram in his [blog](http://blog.nparashuram.com/2014/11/protractor-perf-performance-regression.html#disqus_thread):

browser-perf is the module that collects all the data from the browsers, and converts them into metrics.

Perfjankie is a simple graphing tool built on top of browser-perf that saves the metrics it gets from browser-perf into a couchDB database and has the web pages to display graphs. It runs browser-perf internally to get this data

Protractor-perf is an adapter that makes browser-perf run using Protractor. It picks up protractor's webdriver ID, and lets browser-perf inject the code to gather metrics during your protractor test cases. protractor-perf depends on and uses browser-perf's metric-runner internally.

Comment: question and answer by @Sakshi Singla!!!!The only one that can mark this as correct is you. You may have to wait awhile since you answered it yourself.

Comment: I was looking for an answer on all the forums. Found one and posted here!